# Redirect "/index.php?dir=" to "/"

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Hi
I'm trying to **REDIRECT** a url structure like below:

```
www.example.com/folder/index.php?dir=subfolder/
```

to

```
www.example.com/folder/subfolder/
```

I'll repeat again I **don't** want to **rewrite** the url.
I want the "index.php/dir=" in URL to go away so the "index.html" in "subfolder" is accessed followed by further subfolder with their individual "index.html"(s).
Please advice?

Answer (score 0):

```
 RewriteRule ^/folder/index.php?dir=(.*)$ http://www.example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]
```